# An effective way to read multiple files (python)?

Tags: python

I need to read information from multiple separate files to do some calculation. My current code work perfectly but I need a better -effective- way to do it, like maybe a function.
Thank you in advance.

```py
# read file_1
with open('file_1.txt') as f:
    for line1 in f:
       file_1.append(line1.rstrip())

# read file_2
with open('file_2.txt') as f2:
    for line2 in f2:
       file2.append(line1.rstrip())
       
# read file_3 
with open('file_3.txt') as f3:
    for line3 in f3:
       file3.append(line3.rstrip())

# read file_4 
with open('file_4.txt') as f4:
    for line4 in f4:
       file4.append(line4.rstrip())

# read file_5 
with open('file_5.txt') as f5:
    for line5 in f5:
       file5.append(line5.rstrip())

# read file_6 
with open('file_6.txt') as f6:
    for line6 in f6:
       file6.append(line6.rstrip())
```

Comment: Have you tried using `f.read()` instead of reading each line at a time?

Comment: try multithreading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very repetitive. You can do almost the same thing with the following code:

```
files = [f'file_{i}.txt' for i in range(1,7)]

file_lines={}
# read file_1
for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
        file_lines[file[:-4]] = f.read().strip().split('\n')
```

I'm assuming you wanted a list of lines in `"file_i.txt"` in a variable called `file_i`. So here I've used a dictionary, where your expected `file_i` variable will instead be `file_lines["file_i"]`.

The top line creates a list of all your file names. In the loop, `f.read()` reads all the file contents into one string, then and extra random spaces are stripped, and then the string is split using the newline character to get a list of lines as desired. This is faster than your initial method of looping over the lines.

Now suppose you are dealing with a lot of files of the same type in a location on your computer, it is not recommended to make a list of all the file names manually as we made here. In that case, I would recommend you look into `os.listdir()` or `glob.glob()` which can very easily make the list of file paths for you.

Since you also asked for a function that can do it, here is a sample function you can pass a file path to, and it will return a list of lines:

```
def get_lines(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
            return f.read().strip().split('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you, the  `function`  works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this like this in simpler way,

```
file_names = ['file_1.txt', 'file_2.txt', 'file_3.txt', 'file_4.txt', 'file_5.txt']

for file in file_names:
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            print(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `multithreading` [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) for efficient io

```py
import concurrent.futures

file_names = ['file_1.txt', 'file_2.txt', 'file_3.txt', 'file_4.txt', 'file_5.txt']

def file_processing_operation(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        print(f.read())
        
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(3) as executor:
    executor.map(file_processing_operation, file_names)
```